# ¿Cómo eliminar una imagen Filesystem en Symfomy 6?

Tags: php, symfony, filesystem

Tengo una "galería" de imágenes y mediante un `form` mando el nombre de las imágenes para tratar de eliminarlas usando `Filesystem`, llega el nombre de la imagen, pero no me funciona el eliminar.

**Controlador:**

```php
public function eliminarfoto (ManagerRegistry $doctrine, Request $request, Filesystem $filesystem): Response
{
    $foto =$request->get('casa_foto_url'); //el nombredelaimagen.jpg
    $filesystem->remove(['symlink', '/public/fotos/Casa/', $foto]);
    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_casa');
}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Existe otro método?

Comment: Además de no funcionar... ¿Se genera algún mensaje o excepción de error?

Comment: Tienes como parámetros algo parecido a lo que viene en la documentación de Symphony pero separándolo por comas en lugar de |. En realidad has de pasar un sólo parámetro: un string (del tipo `'/public/fotos/Casa/'.$foto`) o una lista de esos elementos.

Comment: Lo intente así, pero no pasa nada, ni mensaje de error me sale, directamente me redirecciona a la vista de mi return.